# Ubuntu no response from keyboard+mouse

Tags: boot, drivers, nvidia

I recently installed nvidia driver 470 from additional drivers provided in the update software menu on my linux ubuntu 18.04 lts. It was working fine but I needed later to work with carla (self driving car simulator) which requires vulkan compatible driver, so I installed one (I don't remember the link) but when I reboot my laptop it get stucked in the splash screen (ubuntu with the dots underneath but they were showing no progress). So I uninstalled vulkan driver and used back nouveau driver. Linux did no longer stuck in the splash screen but when it arrives to the login screen it becomes irresppnsive to my keyboard and mouse inputs.

Comment: Are you able to login?

Comment: No I can't select my account nor enter my password since mouse and keyboard are not responding

Comment: So basically I see 2 options for you.  1.Do you have or can you make a live disk/USB so you can access the computer?  2.get into the BIOS and try to boot into safe mode.  If you are able to log in you can try and recover the data at least.  From there you have the option of doing a fresh install or trying to figure out what broke.  I would recommend getting the data onto an external drive and reinstalling the OS because whatever is broken is preventing you from logging in.

Comment: Your first option worked for me thanks

Comment: Could you kindly answer your question in the "answer" section and list details of what you did to fix it so as to assist other users.  I'm glad I was able to help.

Answer (score 0):

Using a live usb to copy data on external hard drive, then reinstalling the os  was able to fix the issue.
Fortunately I didnt have large amount of data that I needed to recover. So, this method worked.